# linkingObjectsProperties override from swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-cocoa

I am using realm-cocoa(v1.0.1) with a Swift 2.0 project (need objective-c interoperability) and am having trouble overriding the linkingObjectsProperties method.

I've followed the Realm documentation (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#inverse-relationships) and defined my function override in my RLMObject subclass as follows:

```
override class func linkingObjectsProperties() -> NSDictionary {
    return ["owners": RLMPropertyDescriptor(withClass: Person.self, propertyName: "dogs")]
}
```

The compiler then complains, saying "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

If I prefix the definition with @objc, the error changes to "Overriding method with selector 'linkingObjectsProperties'  has incompatible type '() -> NSDictionary'

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+[RLMObject linkingObjectsProperties]` is exposed to Swift as `class func linkingObjectsProperties() -> [String : RLMPropertyDescriptor]`. Updating your override to match that signature should do the trick.

Comment: It works! Thank you.  I had previously tried -> [NSString: RLMPropertyDescriptor], but I guess "NS" was enough to make the compiler cry.

Comment: For future reference, you can find out how the declaration is exposed to Swift by opening he header in Xcode, then doing Navigate -> Jump to Generated Interface.